# Crawling many pages like internet encyclopedia:Selenium error, HTML table crawling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a crawler of these encyclopedia pages and there are some Selenium and table source crawling errors.

First, there are over 100.000 contents in these wine encyclopedia so I used 'for'. 
Second this crawler must to open and crawl each detailed pages so
I tried to use Selenium chrome driver. 
Third, a table in the detailed page has no id or class name, so I wrote those codes.
When I run this crawler, there are no contents at the chrome page, and these codes don't work.

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
req1 = requests.get('https://terms.naver.com/list.nhn?cid=48159&categoryId=48159&page={}'.format(page))
driver.get(req1)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

> selenium and table crawling codes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
for page in [1.2]:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe') #error
    req1 = requests.get('https://terms.naver.com/list.nhn?cid=48159&categoryId=48159&page={}'.format(page))
    driver.get(req1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
    link = soup.find_all('a')
    for list in link: #detail pages of encyclopedia
      req2 = requests.get('div.view_list_wrap view_list_4>ul>li.view_list_item>div>div.info_area>strong>a')
      driver.get(req2)
      openElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("req2")).click() #move to each detail pages
      w_list = html.select('div[1]>div[3]>div[1]>div[2]>div[2]>div>div>div[2]>div>table') #XPath address of detail page
      title = soup.find('h2',{'class':'headword'}).text #name of wine in detail page
      exp=soup.find('p',{'class':'txt'}).text #explanation of wine in detail page
    for tr in w_list : #information table of wine(type,use etc.)
          one = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          two = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          three = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          four = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          five = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          six = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          seven = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          eight = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          nine = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          ten = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          eleven = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          twelve = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          thirteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          fourteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          fifteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          sixteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          seventeen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          eighteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          nineteen = tr.find('td').find('a').text
          print( 'type:',one, 'use:',two )

data = {'type:',one, 'use:',two}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
df.to_csv('./wine_list.csv', sep=',', encoding='EUC-KR') #save as csv file
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     28     driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
     29     req1 = requests.get('https://terms.naver.com/list.nhn?cid=48159&categoryId=48159&page={}'.format(page))
---> 30     driver.get(req1)
     31     driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Comment: `tr.find('td').find('a')text` should be `tr.find('td').find('a').text` !

Comment: Thanks, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in your `print` statement is that the `:` is outside the `' '` marks, instead of inside. Try it this way and see if that works:

```
print('type: ', one, 'use: ', two)
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed. But still there are some errors in my code.

Comment: @fairystarlight - Yes, I can see it in your edited question. But the new one is a different type of error (generated by selenium) from the one in your original question (generated by Python). Generally speaking, SO prefers that the original question remain as is, and the new error be posted as a separate question.